# Efficiently summing elements in a row of a matrix using Integral Image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, matrix

I would like to make sums for each element of the matrix in an interval of +30 -30 of the curent position. To be more precise suppose I have an element a[i][j] and I like to make the sum of all elements 
 a[i][j - 30] + a[i][j - 29] + a[i][j - 28] + ..... + a[i][ j + 28] + a[i][j+29] + a[i][j + 30;
I have also computed the integral image of the matrix such that I can easily and efficiently make the sum by the formula A + D - C - D;
Here you can see a post how it works
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#integral
My question is how can I make the sum efficiently using the already computed integral image. Or is there another efficient way?

Thank you for your time!

P.S. I know that I could compute the sum for the first 30 elements and at each step add and subtract 1 element - add one from the front and subtract one from the bottom. But I wonder if I could do it faster

Comment: So, you _already_ know how to compute the sum `a[i][j-30] + ... + a[i][j+30]` from the integral image? If so, what's wrong with that? If you're speaking about efficiency, you should also post the execution time of the implementation with the integral image and of your other implementations, and the size of the image. And the code!

Comment: the integral image computation is from open cv so cv::integral(image, outputImage); The idea is how to compute the sum from the integral image of a line. I know how to compute the sum of a square using the integral image but how do I do it for a line ?

Comment: yeah.. so your question is how to compute your sum given the integral image?

Comment: because a == b and c ==d - if abcd is our rectangle ? And I would not actually want to compute the sum by subtracting all sorts of rectangles .. If there is a way to find it from subtractions but if we can find a formula similar to a+d-b-c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using integral images, you are able to get the sum of the values in a given rectangle, like (from Wikipedia):

[image]

You just need to set the proper values for A,B,C,D.

```
Mat1f I; // your integral image

// for each i,j (check boundaries!)
int radius = 30;
float A = I[i-1][j-radius-1];
float B = I[i-1][j+radius];
float C = I[i][j-radius-1];
float D = I[i][j + radius];

float sum = D - B - C + A;
```

Comment: I understand this but what if a == c and b == d ?? This is the question?

Comment: @MMp131316 You want a single row right? so a and b are one row up! (and a and c are onw column left)